# Book on differential Geometry with application to General Relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation

Does anybody know of a good book on differential geometry that has applications to general relativity and also focuses on geometrical intuition?
I need a book that is not as rigorous as one that is targeted for mathematicians but also is not as loose as many books that are intended for physicists(although there are books for physicists that are rigorous enough).
Thanks!

Comment: Sean Carroll's "Lecture Notes on General Relativity" I think fits your request very closely. Also, "Gravitation" by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler is amazing and definitely works hard to develop geometrical intuition.

Comment: @JonHerman But those are not mathematics books

Comment: I really think you need SIA, the whole tone of your question...

Comment: @selfawareuser what do you mean?

Comment: @QuanticMan I mean that before about 1908 calculus was done and results were proven with infinitesimals - this includes most of Riemann's work for example. SIA is an attempt to recreate that methodology. IMHO it's also compatible with limit theory (the [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171828/generating-a-number-with-an-upper-limit/1733192#1733192) is very simple) so the controversy about this was pointless.

Comment: Do you know Frank Morgan's _Riemannian Geometry: a Beginner's Guide_? (I don't know the book well, but if you can borrow a library copy it may be worth a look.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Wow, just checked it out and it's superb! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the statements in the question I would recommend O'Neil's Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to Relativity. O'Neil goes through manifolds and tensors with extreme rigor in the first 4 chapters, but later moves to a viewpoint more suitable for a physicist, so if you have tensor calculus under control you should be able to skip to the middle and get what you're looking for there.